# Proverbs 31:16 - Did the woman use her resources to purchase the field?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, proverbs

זָמְמָ֣ה שָׂ֭דֶה וַתִּקָּחֵ֑הוּ מִפְּרִ֥י כַ֝פֶּ֗יהָ נטע *כ* נָ֣טְעָה *ק* כָּֽרֶם׃

Typically this is translated to indicate the woman bought a field...and from her resources she also planted a vineyard:

> She considereth a field, and buyeth it: with the fruit of her hands she planteth a vineyard. (KJV)

This allocates the woman's resources to the vineyard:

1. The woman buys a field (no mention of where she got the money).
2. With her resources she planted a vineyard.

Is there any basis for seeing the two-fold actions like this:

1. The woman buys a field with the fruit of her hand.
2. She planted a vineyard.

In other words, the woman purchased the field from her own resources and she also planted a vineyard (with no mention of recources).

Answer (score 2):

Given the word order, the traditional translation is most likely correct (though I suppose one could argue ambiguity).

However, I would further point to the Greek Septuagint (LXX), which makes it more explicit in stating that she "planted a possession from the the fruits of her hands." I would also further note that the Syriac Peshitta and Latin Vulgate both agree as well: the vineyard/field/property was planted from the fruits of her hands.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange Saint7992, thanks for contributing - this is a good first answer, though it is somewhat briefer than the typical standard we aim for on the site. Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)